# What does "straddle" in a Bitwise Context mean?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, definition

I am reading about bitfields from:
 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field.

The article mentions "straddl(e)"ing bits.
An example context includes...

> "Adjacent bit field members may be packed to share and straddle the
>   individual bytes."

What does this word mean in a bitwise field?

Comment: Check the second example on that page. The quoted explanation means that the same byte would host multiple fields (which normally does not happen)

Comment: It means that bit fields might span multiple bytes or occupy a single byte and that totally depends on the implementation.

Comment: "span across", part of the bits in one byte, other part in the next byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used that word when writing the page to refer to the situation, as correctly spotted in comments, shown in the 2nd example on that page:

```
#include <iostream>
struct S {
    // will usually occupy 2 bytes:
    // 3 bits: value of b1
    // 2 bits: unused
    // 6 bits: value of b2
    // 2 bits: value of b3
    // 3 bits: unused
    unsigned char b1 : 3, : 2, b2 : 6, b3 : 2;
};
int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(S) << '\n'; // usually prints 2
}
```

Here (assuming `sizeof(S)` is 2) the field `b2` is 6 bits long, the first 3 bits are in the first byte, the second 3 bits are in the second byte. It is straddling two bytes. (the next example shows how to force all 6 bits into one byte)